# Accessing computed values between view models

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I am trying to include multiple viewmodels on one page, I don't want to tie these to specific page IDs like I know you're able to do as I want to be able to use each model potentially more than once on a page and will use the `with` binding.

I'm trying to read the value of `self.total` in `VM1`, from `self.total` in `VM2`, but I'm getting an error:

> Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.

Reading standard `VM1.x` variables from `VM2` seem to work fine, however knockout only complains when trying to get a computed value.

JavaScript:

```
var VM1 = function(parent) {
  var self = this;

  self.costa = 1000;
  self.costb = 500;

  self.total = ko.computed(function(){
    return self.costa + self.costb;
  });
};

var VM2 = function(parent) {
  var self = this;

  self.total = ko.observable(parent.vm1.total);
};

var MasterViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.vm1 = new VM1(self);
  self.vm2 = new VM2(self);
};

window.masterViewModel = new MasterViewModel();

ko.applyBindings(window.masterViewModel);
```

HTML:

```
<div data-bind="with: vm1">
  <p data-bind="text: total()"></p>
</div>
<div data-bind="with: vm2">
  <p data-bind="text: total()"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @haim770 thanks for the response but this also doesn't seem to work for some reason.  The same error message as I was previously seeing. Thanks

Comment: You simply need `self.total = parent.vm1.total;`. And when showing the value, you need to invoke it. For example: `data-bind="text: total()"`.

Comment: Yes that would work, although I want to be able to access this value from the viewmodel in the JS so that I can use it to concatenate values, such as: VM2.total = VM1.total() + VM3.total + VM4.total()

Comment: You haven't supplied any html. How are you binding this computed total value?

Comment: Hi @PhilipBijker I've updated the question above with an example of my markup. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry guys, thanks for the help, @haim770 you were right from the start, I had actually tried this ('total()') but I think it was an issue elsewhere in my code, now it seems to be working fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The solution (as also noted by @haim770) was to call total as a function:
self.total = ko.observable(parent.vm1.total());